# Dealing with decimals with many digits in Pandas,

Tags: python, pandas, variables

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None )
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.200f' % x)


exData = pd.read_csv('AP11.csv',delimiter=';',float_precision=None)
    
x = exData.loc[:,['A','B']]
y = exData.loc[:,['C']]
x
```

my original float on excel is 0.1211101931541032183754113717355410323332315436353654273243543132542237415430173719

what is being displayed is
0.12111019315410319341363987177828676067292690277099609375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...

this is not a display issue. something in pandas rounds my float. i don't want to round any number for it will affect the result of my string. because this is originally a string that is converted to a float. i tried to use int64 but it can't handle big numbers. so instead i decided to use floats with "0.mystring" to not get "inf" displayed in pandas. and i get it rounded. is machine learning limited by these missy variables? or is there another way to deal with big numbers without rounding, displaying inf?

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `decimal` instead of float. Just put

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

at the top of your code, and write your floats as

```
x = Decimal(0.121110193154103218375411371735541032333231543635365427324354313254223741543017371)
```

`decimal` is a library for floats with a dynamic length, rather than rounded.
Generally you should avoid `float`s, as they can have strange irregularities and roundings. Often when operations are performed on them, they can have a series of zeros and then some other numbers, when it should just have a few decimal places.

Comment: thank you but this solved one part only. i have a full column of x data i want to convert it to decimal and feed it to the machine.

Comment: @DiaEid Apologies, but I do not understand you. What is the other question?

Comment: Sorry i haven't made my point clear in the question. what i meant is i have a full column, data.csv file read by pandas. i want all of it to be of type decimal but i can't find the syntax anywhere. and also can keras accept decimal as a machine learning data type. thank you

Comment: @DiaEid Ah. I am afraid that I am inexperienced with `pandas`. I did not realize that was part of the issue. I will do some research, and edit my answer when I have something.

Comment: @DiaEid I don't know if I will be able to help you with this. No matter what converters I use, or if I have it stored as a string, it only prints a total of 7 characters (5 decimals places). Greatest apologies.